# Selenium webdriver - How to set "extensions-update-frequency" in ChromeOptions class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chromium, chrome-options

It seems you can't automate an extension update on the chrome extensions page using selenium webdriver (by clicking on the "update now" button.  The button gets clicked but the click event is not registering any update as it should.  After a little reading it seems that chrome launches with a set of default arguments/parameters which omit how often your chrome extensions should update.

I believe the default time is around 5 hours and I'm lead to believe you can overwrite it by passing the following argument in the chromeoptions class like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("extensions-update-frequency=45")
```

I've tried this but having no joy.  If I pass the flag directly to chrome.exe it works just fine.

Has anyone had any success with this?